# how to achieve when-then-return in groovy spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

i have a service class to test  which has another service autorwired in it.
The other service refers to another autowired dao jpa repository. I am trying to mock it and get the result but its returning NUll

```java
public ServiceClass {
  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  public int method test(date) {
    int result= methodB(date)
    return result;
  }

  public int methodB {
    return serviceB.getData("test");
  }
}
```

ServiceB is as:

```java
public class ServiceB {
  @Autowired
  private DaoRepository daoRepository;
        
  public int getData(String test){
    return DaoRepository.findIdByKey(test).getId()
  }
}
```

In Groovy:

```groovy
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles(""test)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class ServiceClassSpec extends Specification {
  @Autowired
  ServiceClass serviceClass
        
  @SpyBean
  ServiceB serviceB
  @MockBean
  private DaoRepository daoRepository
        
  def 'test'() {
    given:
    def Task task=new Task()
    task.setKey("test")
    task.setId(10)
    daoRepository.findIdByKey("test") >> task

    when:
    def result=serviceClass.getData("test")

    then:
    result==1
  } 
}
```

Code for repository:

```java
public interface DaoRepository extends DaoParentRepository<Task> {}
```

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DaoParentRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
  public T findByKey(String key);
  public T findIdByKey(String key);
}
```

Though the `daoRepository` is mocked but returns `null` for `DaoRepository.findIdByKey(test)` and hence a null pointer exception

Comment: Can someone please answer this query.

Comment: Did you forget to initialise `test`? You seem to call `findById(test)` with an uninitialised variable. `ServiceB ServiceB` also looks strange, the variable having the same name as the class. Is this some kind of pseudo code? It is also difficult to say much about your `DaoRepository` mock because you hide the source code of that class. I cannot see what `findById(..)` returns, but I already see that you didn't stub its result, so of course you get `null`. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the parts you think are relevant.

Comment: please let me know how do u stub daorepository.. I have done  @MockBean
  private DaoRepository daoRepository and assumed this will do the stub for mock. Corrected code and added repository code for reference,

Comment: Please let me know how do i stub the daoRepository

Comment: I have stubbed dao response as: daoRepository.findIdByKey("test") >> task still it returns a null

Comment: I'd suggest to use the spock-spring module and its `@SpringBean` support http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_using_code_springbean_code